# What do I need to be able to put something in the executable svn section?

Tags: r, github, svn

[image: Coursera SVN]

In the course I am taking, Github is being linked with R. But in the executable svn section I cannot put anything. And I don't know if I have to download something or what I'm supposed to do. In the course they do not explain anything about that point, which makes me think that it is something obvious or simple, but I have no idea about it.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about linking GitHub and RStudio, then you don't need to set anything in the SVN field.

Having specified the Git executable is enough.
Make sure your [public SSH key is registered to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

The OP reports:

> A friend told me to right click on the r icon and run as an administrator

That means the SSH keys might have been accessible only from admin account, as opposed to regular user account.

Comment: The key is registered. I tried everything and I read several things but I could not solve it. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: In fact, wanting to create a new project, without putting a repository in git, I am denied access. Doesn't this have to do with the mistake of not being able to link git with r?

Comment: @Ozymandias Can you create a new repo in Git, and a new R project, in command line, then try to load it in the IDE?

Comment: @Ozymandias Considering a new repo is local, it should not be linked to your GitHub issues.

Comment: With great joy I share that I could fix it. A friend told me to right click on the r icon and run as an administrator haha and voila, I could move on. Thank you very much for taking the time to respond

Comment: @Ozymandias Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.